# One list and Two Columns unordered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

I'm trying to make a display a list in two columns.

Odd numbers in the left, even numbers in the right.

This is what I mean:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                    col-md-9                        |
+------------------------+---------------------------+
|     1.                 |        2                  |
|     3.                 |        4.                 |
|     5.                 |        6.                 |
|     7.                 |        8.                 |
|     9.                 |       10.                 |
|                        |                           |
|                        |                           |
|                        |                           |
|                        |                           |
+------------------------+---------------------------+
```

and my code is:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
   <ul>
      <li>1.</li>
      <li>2.</li>
      <li>3.</li>
      <li>4.</li>
      <li>5.</li>
      <li>6.</li>
      <li>7.</li>
      <li>8.</li>
      <li>9.</li>
      <li>10.</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?
ps:To expand the list, i use while() looping

Answer (score 0):

> Please check in full screen i have use md so currently it will show in 1 li in each row.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-9">
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-md-6">1.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">2.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">3.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">4.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">5.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">6.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">7.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">8.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">9.</li>
    <li class="col-md-6">10.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `col-md-12` on the parent, so the columns have at least the same width?

Comment: Not required to add col-md-12 depend row will use the 100% layout of your parent.

Comment: The row does, but the cells don't. They are not 50% each.

Comment: depends on your requirement you can change the cell width.

Answer (score 0):

For the bootstrap dislikers amongst us:

```html
<style>
    .ul-two-cols {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        listItemStyle: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    .ul-two-cols > li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
    }
</style>
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <ul class="ul-two-cols">
    <li>1.</li>
    <li>2.</li>
    <li>3.</li>
    <li>4.</li>
    <li>5.</li>
    <li>6.</li>
    <li>7.</li>
    <li>8.</li>
    <li>9.</li>
    <li>10.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```